# ERROR: Method does not override any method from its superclass

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a table view ui programmatically and the code i followed has no problems but mine kept telling me i have the error above? Please help

The error shows that it is at this line: `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

This is a fragment of my code:-

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added the delegates ? can you please show me the error what you getting ?

Comment: What is the class that this code is in? Show the class definition line. Also, the function takes `IndexPath` not `NSIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure but seem you have tableView in UIViewController? If like this, we don't need **override** before **func cellForRowAtIndexPath** . Just remove **override** text.

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is Swift 2 code. Please look for tutorials providing contemporary code.

The syntax of Swift 3+ is

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

The `override` keyword is only required if the class is a subclass of `UITableViewController`

Answer (score -1):

If you use `UIViewController`, just add `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods as like below example and don't include override keyword:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    }

    //Other UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods goes here
}
```

If you use `UITableViewController`, you can override the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods as like below example:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController{

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    }

    //override other UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate methods here
}
```

Hope it helps!